# Why some server requires './' to run scripts but others don't?

Tags: scripts, execute-command

I'm wondering why some Ubuntu servers are different.

I have two Ubuntu 12.04 server which are running a web application. Today I tried to run an sh file from its folder. Server 1 can run shell without ./ but server 2 requires it. Both have 777 permission.

Comment: What are the content of the $PATH variable on both servers ?

Comment: They all using BASH shell? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @P.-H.Lin It is both bash. (both prints /bin/bash)

Comment: @Benoit It is also both prints following:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Comment: @Batbayar are you sure that there is no `:.` appended on server 1? This could be easily overseen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. I double checked it by copying to text editor.

Comment: There was a mistake made by my UNIX professor back in the day, where he left a : on the end of the path declaration. This results in . being in the path even though you can't see it. (Empty entry in PATH acts like . for some reason -- natural would have been / but that's not what happened.)

Answer (score 9):

Normally scripts/programs in the current folder are not executed on linux/unix.

Scripts/programs are only executed when the script/program can be found in the `$PATH` variable.

So when the path is not included in the `$PATH` variable you have to give the path to the script/program to run it. To execute a script/program in the current folder you have to prepend it with `./` which denotes the currect folder.

Please check that the `$PATH` variable on both servers are the same.

Based on your comment about the `$PATH` variable I suspect that one of the scripts is in a folder that is found by the `$PATH` variable whereas the other is in another folder.

**Attention**

It is a bad idea to include `./` in your `$PATH`. This way a user can create a malicious command (such as `ls`) and guide you into the folder where he saves it. Then you will execute the local version instead of the system command (if the current folder is placed in `$PATH` before `/bin`).

Comment: also both sh script placed under /install/test